# Heroku Error: Cannot find module 'knex' with nodejs deploy

Tags: node.js, heroku, knex.js

I am tring to deploy a nodejs application, but I got the error `Error: Cannot find module 'knex'`. In Heroku bash, there are no knex folder in node_modules. I installed knex through npm in Heroku bash, but no success. I changed my package.json like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143925/heroku-cannot-find-module-mongodb), but the error stills the same.
Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "control",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start":"node index.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "consign": "0.1.6",
    "cors": "2.8.4",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "knex": "0.19.5",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "passport": "0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "4.0.0",
    "pg": "7.4.3",
    "pm2": "3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "nodemon": "1.18.4"
  },
   "engines" : { 
     "node" : "10.16.3",
     "npm": "6.9.0"
     } 
}
```

Comment: "I installed knex through npm in Heroku bash"—that will never work. When you run a command on Heroku you get a new one-off dyno. Any changes you make will be immediately lost when the command exits (in this case, when you exit bash). Even if it persisted, it wouldn't affect your other dynos (most importantly the ones running your web process).

Comment: Are you entirely sure that you've deployed to Heroku using the `package.json` you show in your question? Do you see `knex` being installed in your deploy output?

Comment: I am sure. In deploy output, I can only see `Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)`, nothing about knex specifically.

Comment: And if you search your `package-lock.json` for `knex` you find it in there?

Comment: Yes. I tried to use `knex` version 0.15.2 and it works, maybe its something with the version 0.19.5

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use yarn and the most current version of **nodejs** it is likely that you will have problems with the version of **nodejs**. here is the [guide](https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version) to update libraries.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31513253)